# How to create a program which is working similar like RAID1 (mirroring)?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to create a simple program which is working very similar to RAID1. It should work like this:
First i want to give the primary HDD-s drive letter and than the secondary one. I will only write to the primary HDD! If any new data is copied to the primary HDD it should automatically copy it to the secondary one.
I need some help where should i start all this? How to monitor the written data in the primary HDD? Obviously there are many ways to do what i want (i think), but i need the simpliest way.
If this isn't so complicated, than how can i handle that case if the primary HDD has two or more partition, because then i should check the secondary HDD's partition too, and then create/resize them if necessary?

Thanks in advance!

kampi

Comment: How familiar are you with writing file system device drivers?

Comment: Hi! I didn't write such a program yet, but everything has to begin once :) Why do you ask?

Comment: Because that's what required to make this work.  You'll have to cross "simple" out of your requirements.  Read Walter Oney's books.

Comment: doesn't windows include some soft raid?

Comment: As far as I heard, IFS drivers are known to be black magic also among developers of kernel-mode code; not the easiest thing to start with... @Javier: yes, they are the so-called "dynamic disks".

Comment: I would leave RAID to hardware, any kind of software emulation won't perform as well and will be susceptible to OS issues (e.g. the inconvenient BSOD). This reminds me of Windows' old Internet Connection Sharing, where Windows would be used as a quasi-router; another task better left to the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of mirroring disk writes to another disk in real time is the basis for high availability, and implementing these schemes are not trivial.

The company I work for makes [DoubleTake](http://www.visionsolutions.com/Products/Vision-Products-Overview.aspx), which does real time mirroring & replication of file based IO to local or remote volumes. This is a little different than what you are describing, which appears to be block based disk/volume replication, but many of the concepts are similar.

For file based replication, there are a quite a few nasty scenarios, i'll describe a few:

1. Synchronizing the contents of one volume to another volume, keeping in mind that changes can occur while you are doing this. I suppose you could simply this by requiring that volumes start out totally formatted. But for people that have data that will not be a good solution!
2. keeping up with disk changes: What if the volume you are mirroring to is slower than the source volume? Where do you buffer? To Disk? Memory?

Anyways we use a kernel mode file system filter driver to capture the disk IO, and then our user mode service grabs this IO and forwards it to a local or remote disk.

If you want to learn about file system filtering, one of the best books (its old but good) is File System Internals, by Rajeev Nagar. Its a must read for doing any serious work with file system filters.

Also take a look at the file system filter samples on the Windows 7 WDK, its free, and they have good file mon examples that will get you seeing disk changes pretty quickly.

Good Luck!